# Max HTTP response size in Volley Android

Tags: android, android-volley

I'm using Volley to make a server call, which can in some cases return a large response - a few megabytes JSON.

When the server response is more "normal" size, everything works, but with a large payload Volley throws a `NetworkError` without any details attached and logs a weird message - `BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 200`.

I'm pretty sure the issue is with response size, so my question is whether there a known limit for HTTP request/response size in Android/Volley, or a setting to change it. I know some HTTP libraries have it.

I know the server is fine as there are other clients using the same server endpoint in the same way.

I started debugging inside the library code and found that the response code is indeed `200` and the correct data is being received. The request content is being copied from response stream in chunks, but at some point something goes wrong in the copying.

This is the closest I could get to the original exception. Apparently, a `java.net.ProtocolException` is getting thrown sometime during the while loop at first breakpoint shown on the picture. You can also see the actual JSON content is there.

[image: original exception]

Then this exception gets handled and re-thrown a couple more times:

[image]

Comment: are you using `JsonObjectRequest`?

Comment: Yes, I'm using `JsonObjectRequest`

Comment: try just for testing if `StringRequest` could be performed, if so it would mean ... some OOM or something...

Comment: or even [custom request](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/request-custom) so that nothing but raw  `byte[] response.data` is allocated

Comment: looking at the profiler and it doesn't show any memory spike at all. The error seems to to occur before JSON parsing. I'll try custom request

Comment: so first try build-in `StringRequest` and for example `Log.d` first few chars from the response

Comment: but looking at the [sources](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley/+/43950676303ff68b23a8b469d6a534ccd1e08cfc/src/com/android/volley/toolbox/BasicNetwork.java#140) it seems you are getting `IOException` thrown from `entityToBytes` method where the `PoolingByteArrayOutputStream bytes` is written

Comment: I did try the `CustomRequest` and it didn't work. The error occurs before any parsing takes place. Added more info to the question.

Comment: yup, this is what i said in my previous comment - they first read the entire response data to `byte[]` and it causes the problems - i am afraid you have to switch to retrofit/okhttp - i believe the are working on streams